# Dymola Command to Maximize or Manipulate Size or Placement of Plot Window

Tags: modelica, dymola

Is there a command to maximize or manipulate in any way the size and placement of a plot window in Dymola?

After creating a plot using createPlot(), I would like to maximize that window within its allowed area of the screen.

No resource, either online or printed, has indicated how to do this, and none has said it couldn't be done. I am hoping someone can point me to a source that tells me how, or tells me to stop trying.

Here is the entirety of my test script:

```
simulateModel("TIL_AddOnTraining.Example07a", stopTime=300, method="dassl", tolerance=1e-005, resultFile="Example07a");

createPlot(
    id=0,
    position={0, 0, 857, 705},
    x="valve.summary.dp",
    y={"valve.summary.m_flow_A"},
    grid=true,
    colors={{255,0,0}},
    thicknesses={0.7},
    autoscale = true
    );

[Here is where I would like the command to maximize window called "Plot [0*]".]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like this is not possible for plot windows. Only animation windows can be maximized with animationPosition(position=[...], maximized=true).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the feasibility of doing this in Dymola, but here's a way to create and fine tune plot windows for Modelica using Mathematica and SystemModeler.

```
Needs["WSMLink`"]
sim=WSMSimulate["HelloWorld"];
plot=WSMPlot[sim,{"x","der(x)"},PlotLabel->"Very Interesting Plot\[Dash]Full Screen"];
CreateDocument[plot,WindowSize->Full]
```

[image: A full screen plot]

The setting `WindowSize` can be changed to different options to select a fraction of the window, full screen, pixel size, and so on.